# Is it fair to compare the significance of overlap of 2 different sized sets with a third set using Fisher's exact test?

Tags: statistical-significance, fishers-exact-test

Say I choose 3 sets of genes $A$, $B$ and $C$ from an entire set of 20K genes, and I want to see whether set $A$ has a more significant gene overlap with set $C$ than set $B$. That's, I want to compute a p-value $p$ associated with the overlap of $A$ and $C$, and another p-value $q$ associated with the overlap of $B$ and $C$, and I want to check whether $p < q$. I know that the p-values $p$ and $q$ in this problem can be computed using Fisher's exact test. My question is as follows: If the set $A$ is bigger than set $B$ (e.g. 150 genes in $A$ vs. 30 genes in $B$), is it still a fair comparison when I compare the overlaps of each set with $C$ based on the p-values computed using Fisher's exact test?

Answer (score 0):

**Reply from biostars.org:**
The overlap between two sets follows a hypergeometric distribution. When doing a hypergeometric test, the various sizes are taken into account so because Fisher's exact test is based on the hypergeometric distribution, it also takes sample size into consideration. Note that for this (and the Chi-squared test), you need to use counts not proportions.
So if you want to know if A∩C is more likely than B∩C, you can compare the p-values.

Comment: This answer neither links to the source nor credits the author. It doesn't follow the requirement to properly acknowledge sources. It's also important for you to check whether you actually have permission to repost answers given there; ideally any license should be explicitly mentioned.